# How to convert a pdf to 4-up in landscape mode (ideally using ghostscript)?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have pdf slides in landscape mode and would like to create a new pdf file containing the slides 4-up (in landscape mode again) like this:

```
-----------------
|   1   |   2   |
-----------------
|   3   |   4   |
-----------------
```

I know that there is `pdfjam` (which can be used like this `pdfjam --fitpaper true --nup 2x2 --delta '1mm 1mm' --scale 0.98 infile.pdf`), but it does not preserve hyperlinks -- `gs` does, though. I am wondering how one could use `gs` to achieve the task (?)

Alternatively, I mainly use 4-up to print slides. I couldn't manage to use `lpr` for achieving this. If someone has an idea for that, this would be interesting as well.

Comment: Does this solve the task (lpr Q)? `lpr -o number-up=4 -o number-up-layout=btlr document.pdf `. [Ref - fsu.edu](http://www.math.fsu.edu/Computer/printer_cl.math)

Comment: This is the closest I've come to a solution, but it still prints the pages in portrait format... (no matter whether I use `-o landscape` or not): `lpr -o sides=one-sided -o landscape -o number-up=4 -o number-up-layout=btlr -o fitplot document.pdf`; might be the printer... that's actually why I was looking for way to first create a correct pdf file which I can then just send to the printer

Comment: If it is the printer you could try to print to pdf first. If in apt world: `apt-get install cups-pdf`, then `lpr .... -P PDF`. File should be stored in `~/PDF/` by default. *(At least you can play around without wasting ink and paper ;))*

Comment: That's indeed a good idea. I installed `cups-pdf` and executed the command again with `-P PDF`. I obtained `lpr: No such file or directory`. I even created `~/PDF` but this didn't change anything.

Comment: Here it worked out of the box. On install two new files was created: cups-pdf.conf and PDF.ppd. [Diff here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4Zwnyr3T). Perhaps you have to try to re-run [cups-genppdupdate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cups-genppdupdate), restart CUPS, check [localhost:631/](http://localhost:631/) etc. Also: Your `pdfjam` and my first posted `lpr` gives same result here – landscape PDF became 4 paged landscape.

Comment: Okay, I finally managed to install the pdf printer. Your command indeed works (I should not have used `-o landscape` since the slides were already in landscape). However, I applied it to slides in landscape format which contained some pictures. Strangely, some of the pages containing pictures appeared in portrait format in the resulting pdf. Don't know how this can be avoided. Also, the resulting pdf is quite big. After all, I guess it's not a particularly good idea to use lpr for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with LaTeX. It puts 6 4"×6" postcards onto a 11"×17" sheet of paper including rotation to fit the two on the side.

This could be improved by adding cut marks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=17in,paperwidth=11in,margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% \usepackage{graphics}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}%.75mm is rather small


\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(4.6,-4.4){\hbox{\includegraphics{pdfs/1.pdf}}}
\put(4.6,-8.5){\hbox{\includegraphics{pdfs/2.pdf}}}
\put(4.6,-12.6){\hbox{\includegraphics{pdfs/3.pdf}}}
\put(4.6,-16.7){\hbox{\includegraphics{pdfs/4.pdf}}}
\put(0.3,-2.4){\hbox{\includegraphics[angle=270]{pdfs/5.pdf}}}
\put(0.3,-8.5){\hbox{\includegraphics[angle=270]{pdfs/6.pdf}}}

\put(0,0){\line(3,-0.35){4}} % NEED TO MAKE CUT MARKS
\end{picture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score -3):

you can try with http://posterazor.sourceforge.net

I only convert a image. I dont know if convert text is possible.

Comment: One of the problem here is url conversion, so if your solution works only with image it's definitly not the good one I Guess

Comment: But if you dont have other solution you can convert pdf to image whit 'convert' command and then use posterazor.